# whats the advantage of using guards in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

```
count_instances :: (Int)->([Int])->Int 
count_instances x [] = 0 
count_instances x (t:ts) 
    | x==t = 1+(count_instances x ts) 
    | otherwise = count_instances x ts
```

i just want to know whats so good about using guards in this Question ?

Comment: Please write questions in a readable and comprehensible manner. Read the StackOverflow  help for some guidance.

Answer (score 3):

A guard can be a way to write only one half of an `if-then-else` expression; you can omit the `else` and have a partial function.

```
-- Leave the function undefined for x /= y
foo x y | x == y = ...
```

You can do the same with a `case` statement, but it's more verbose

```
foo x y = case x == y of
          True -> ...
```

It's also easier to list several unrelated conditions as a set of alternatives than it is with a nested `if-then-else` or `case` expressions.

```
foo x y | p1 x y = ...
foo x y | p2 x y = ...
foo x y | p3 x y = ...
foo x y = ...
```

vs

```
foo x y = if p1 x y then ... 
          else (if p2 x y then ...
                else (if p3 x y then ... else ...))
```

Comment: Minor point: there's no need to increase the indentation of the last if-then-else chain. Such chain is a relatively common pattern in many imperative languages, and is frequently written without the staircase indentation. Being a common idiom (elsewhere), it's not terribly unreadable if indented simply.

Answer (score 2):

A guard is haskell's most general **conditional statement**, like if/then/else in other languages.

Your code shows a straight forward implementation of counting contents of a list equal to a given parameter. This is a good example to learn how haskell's recursion works.

An alternative implementation would be

```
count_instances :: Int -> [Int] -> Int
count_instances i = length . filter (==i)
```

that reuses already existing functions from the Prelude module. This is shorter and probably more readable.

Comment: yes i was using length . filter earlier but i was told not to use it and try and do it with non haskell library functions supposably and thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 2):

Patterns with guards are probably the most concise way to write code that otherwise would require nested case/if expressions.

Not the least advantage is that a **where** clause applies to all the guards right hand sides. This is why your example could be even more concise:

```
count_instances :: (Int)->([Int])->Int 
count_instances x [] = 0 
count_instances x (t:ts) 
    | x==t = 1+rest 
    | otherwise = rest
    where rest = count_instances x ts
```

Comment: Interesting. For what is worth, in my own coding style, I forbid myself using `where` after guards (or anything else which spans over multiple lines), since I find such code harder to read -- perhaps I am too used to look _up_ to see where an identifier was defined. So, I consider the ability of using a `where` after guards a disadvantage :-P

Comment: @chi while I respect your favorite choice, I recommend reading SJP's paper where he introduces and motivates guards. Even if you don't like it, you cannot but admit that a where clause can reduce code duplication and is soetimes the only way to do so. Also, better editor support can help with the "where is it defined" problem.

Comment: Well, sometimes I use `let` followed by `case`+guards. Multi-way `if` is newer, but I should consider using it more. I know my choice is not as popular as the style above. I wish SPJ went for `where` before guards :) or some other "define before you use" syntax. Should an occasion arise where there's no other reasonably simple alternative, I'll probably use `where` after guards, I guess. I'm not extremely dogmatic about it, but enough so to look hard for alternatives.

Comment: You could obtain a similar effect by pulling the shared recursive call out of the guard and into common code, which may be more palatable to you? `count_instances x (t:ts) = count_instances x ts + this where {this | x == t = 1 | otherwise = 0}`